# Four column layout bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got give a jsfiddle that asked the following:

Four Column Layout: Using a Bootstrap class, edit these divs from stacked to a 4 column layout

HTML:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
div.a{
  background: #00FF00;
}
div.b{
  background: #1234FF;
}
div.c{
  background: #FbbF00;
}
div.d{
  background: #FF3344;
}
```

For my answer I did the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span 3">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="span 3">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="d"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="span 3">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="span 3">
    <div class="d"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  div{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  div.a{
    background: #00FF00;
  }
  div.b{
    background: #1234FF;
  }
  div.c{
    background: #FbbF00;
  }
  div.d{
    background: #FF3344;
  }
```

But I was told I was wrong with no explanation. Does anyone know how to achieve four stacked columns using bootstrap for the above code?

Comment: Clearly the task is asking you to use Bootstraps grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/yczxm9px/1/

```css
.div{
    height: 50px;
  }
  div.a{
    background: #00FF00;
  }
  div.b{
    background: #1234FF;
  }
  div.c{
    background: #FbbF00;
  }
  div.d{
    background: #FF3344;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 div a">
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 div b">
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 div c">
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 div d">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the class are bootstrap class.

- **xs** for Extra Small Screen
- **sm** for Small Screen
- **md** for Medium Screen
- **lg** for Large Screen.